# Video edit software with UI to make cuts from movies on Windows

Tags: windows, video, gui, video-editing, wysiwyg

Is there a video editing software for Windows which could be effectively used for cutting pieces (extract to separate files) from favorite movies and videos with the following features:
0. UI (like in Adobe products) and simplicity is key for me here. I need to see the video during the work, easily tune parameters, etc.

1. Ability to cut the fragment and export it without recompression, just copying the stream? (Sure, I am aware about key frames, progressive compression, etc., but maybe, starting from the last key frame, etc.)
2. An option like "Minimum losses while recompression, zero if possible". I really want to store the videos in the best quality I could, not expecting loses from recompression. I just need scissors.
3. Ability to work transparently with mkv container without any external packers/unpackers.
4. Use of GPU for fast compression/decompression.

Optional

1. Ability to keep the subtitles for these fragments.

I used to use `VirtualDub` software for this, but it doesn't support many new features and codecs, so no way to use it.

Free software would be the best, but commercial is an option, as well.

Comment: ffmpeg? Don't know about points 3 or 4, but it's your best bet for points 1 and 2 for sure.

Comment: @Destroy666, I know `ffmpeg` as a command-line tool with a very sophisticated settings, parameters, etc. I am not sure even if it has the GUI for Windows and WYSIWYG interface is key for me here. Updated the question to be more precise here, thank you!